# Is a string the most efficient way to send this data?

Tags: c, bluetooth, arduino, serial-port

I'm using an Arduino to send over 3 axis' of rotation and 3 button states. Currently I'm formatting this to a string like this:

"#235#12#32$TlR"

Where the 3 first numbers are the rotation, t, l, r are the buttons, where a capital tells me if the button is pressed.

I'm writing my data to a com port using:

> Serial.println

All works great using my a cable, but when I switch over to BlueTooth (I have a module attached to it) the rotation has a big delay.

Could the string be too big to be send at a rate of 30 times a second through BlueTooth? Is there a way to format my data in smaller packages?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's quite likely to be too small: some Nagle-like algorithm is waiting to see if more data will arrive so that a more efficient, larger airside PDU can be sent.

Comment: Anyway, you APDU is so small already that there is not going to be any point is shrinking it further.

Answer (score 0):

Binary would certainly be smaller - Assuming every axis would fit into a byte and the buttons into an 8-bit bitfield, you could shrink your 14-bytes bpackage into 3 or possibly 4 bytes (maybe adding some sort of framing). This would obviously reduce used bandwidth by a factor of at least 3 (but complicating your pogram, though. If everything fits into bytes, you would at least not face problems of platform byte order)

From Bluetooth, you can, *under close to ideal conditions*, expect a bandwidth of ~80kbit/s. - 20 * 30 bytes / second should easily be achievable, even if you stick with the ASCII protocol that you have.

Comment: Indeed it does not seem to be a bandwidth problem, more likely a latency issue.  The Bluetooth driver on the sending side is probably waiting for more data before the frame is aired.

Comment: Right. But that wasn't the question ;) My assumption was the OP would want to transmit as much positional packets as possible - i.e. a continuous data stream.

Comment: Thanks tofro. Unfortunately I'm not that familiar with converting string data to bytes. 

I think I can just send a 0 or 1 for button states, and depending on the position of the bit in the array, I can determine which bit represents which button. But as for a 3 digit long number, should I look into an ascii table ?

Comment: Well I guess you both are right! Enough packages with the smallest amount of latency. Hmh. I think latency is my biggest worry tbh.

Comment: If *latency* is the main thing you are trying to avoid, you should concentrate on *keeping the stream of bytes going* - In this case I would, at least for the moment, stay with the ASCII transfer that you have and not try to make the packet shorter. You can come back to this once you actually see you are using too much bandwidth.

Comment: Ok, I googeled some more info about reducing the latency of a Bluetooth module, I think I can get started with this. Thanks for the advice everyone!

Comment: The airside protocols are optimized around streaming large amounts of data, (look at typical 'tooth usage).  For that requirement, low latency is sacrificed in favour of large buffers and efficient low-overhead streaming.  The worst loading to apply to such a link is intermittent bursts of small packets;(

Comment: @MartinJames So what you're saying is that my packages are too small, which requires more processing time, which delays the latency?

Comment: Large packets and large buffers actually do not require more CPU time, but rather less (packet overhead is reduced vs. payload). On the other hand, large packets *delay* the overall packet throughput and increase latency because the driver is waiting for more data to come (filling up the large buffers) before it *actually sends* your data. It might well be that it collects 2 or three of your records into one packet before it actually sends them.